# Moving circles in android

Tags: java, android

I have a task. It's to draw some (more than one) circles moving around the screen. They must start moving after click on them. I have the code only for one circle. Give me the way how to do this task, for example, 5 circles. Thanks in advance!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new MyView(this));
    }

    class MyView extends View {
        //public    Paint c;
        public  Paint p;

        private static final int RADIUS = 46;

        private int centerX;
        private int centerY;
        private int speedX = 50;
        private int speedY = 40;
        //private Paint paint; // Создай его где-нибудь там в конструкторе


        public MyView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            p = new Paint();
            p.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldW, int oldH) {
            centerX = w / 2;
            centerY = h / 2;
        }

        protected void onDraw(Canvas c) {
            int w = getWidth();
            int h = getHeight();
            centerX += speedX;
            centerY += speedY;
            int rightLimit = w - RADIUS;
            int bottomLimit = h - RADIUS;

            if (centerX >= rightLimit) {
                centerX = rightLimit;
                speedX *= -1;
            }
            if (centerX <= RADIUS) {
                centerX = RADIUS;
                speedX *= -1;
            }
            if (centerY >= bottomLimit) {
                centerY = bottomLimit;
                speedY *= -1;
            }
            if (centerY <= RADIUS) {
                centerY = RADIUS;
                speedY *= -1;
            }

            c.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, RADIUS, p);
            postInvalidateDelayed(200);  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is your problem/question with that code?

Comment: hey. were you able to solve the problem. I am facing a similar problem

Answer (score 1):

you have to change this part:

```
  private int centerX;
  private int centerY;
  private int speedX = 50;
  private int speedY = 40;
```

and convert it to the

```
class Circle {
  private int centerX;
  private int centerY;
  private int speedX = 50;
  private int speedY = 40;
  // add constructor here and other things
};
```

then make a collection of your circles: `ArrayList<Circle> circles`, and then instead of

```
centerX += speedX;
centerY += speedY;
int rightLimit = w - RADIUS;
int bottomLimit = h - RADIUS;

if (centerX >= rightLimit) {
  centerX = rightLimit;
  speedX *= -1;
}
if (centerX <= RADIUS) {
  centerX = RADIUS;
  speedX *= -1;
}
if (centerY >= bottomLimit) {
  centerY = bottomLimit;
  speedY *= -1;
}
if (centerY <= RADIUS) {
  centerY = RADIUS;
  speedY *= -1;
}
```

you have to do it for every circle, like

```
for( i=0; i<circles.size(); i++) {
    circles[i].centerX += circles[i].speedX;
    circles[i].centerY += circles[i].speedY;

    // и так далее...
 }
```

Comment: Hi , lenik can you tell me how to know if a user has clicked on a circle after drawing it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call draw circle 5 times with different centerx ,centerY ,Radius and p