# Making a user able to interact with a "ball" on the screen?

Tags: android, gestures

I am trying to learn some more about gestures and graphics in Android, so I am trying to make a sort of game where you start with a ball (just a red circle) in the middle of the screen, and if you swipe in a direction, the ball will be launched in that direction, bouncing of the screen etc. Now, I have succeeded in detecting when somebody swipes in a certain direction, and currently I just display the direction on the screen. My question is: how do I continue? How can I draw the ball, make the user able to move it and make it bounce off the sides of the screen? I think I need to use onDraw somehow, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a guy with similar problem, he has managed to get circles going around the screen and bouncing from the edges, you may use his code as a basis for your drawing and animation routines: [Moving circles in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13360021/moving-circles-in-android)